# Magento 2 - How to create a module that adds a flag to the product and restricts adding it to the cart before logging in?

Tags: magento2, products, login, restriction

I'm new to magento 2 and would like to know if it is possible to make a module that generates flags on products with purchase restriction?
For example, the product can only be added to the cart when the user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your requirement in details. My suggestion is that we can use the Observer event in this case. We catch event `checkout_cart_product_add_before` on the frontend to prevent non-logged customer adding product to cart.

> that generates flags on products with purchase restriction

An easiest way is to create a product attribute.

Comment: Is this capture from the module frontend file I am creating? I don't get it yet, I'm extremely new to Magento

Comment: What I'm thinking of doing is creating a product group that can only be purchased with login. Therefore the flag indicating the restriction

Comment: Khoa, My observer I did like this:

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_before">
        <observer name="access_verification" instance="Lucsfernandes\FlagIndication\Observer\VerificationAccess"/>
    </event>
</config>`
Is that correct?